# Playframework [Scala]: Class not found in classpath in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, derby, playframework-2.5

I have added to `build.sbt` the Apache Derby jar:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.derby" % "derby" % "10.14.1.0" % Test
```

I also ran `activator update`, which seemed to work fine.

I need to embed Derby's database within the application, so I'm trying to instantiate the connection to it:

```
 println(1)
 Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance()
 println(2)
 val url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/tempdb;create=true;user=me;password=mine"
 val conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)   
 println(3)
```

The above code only prints `1` and then generates an exception. I think it is mostly because the class is not in the classpath (the exception message is just the class name). What is missing here?

Comment: please could you add the exception you are getting?

Comment: Indeed, no exception message "is just the class name". Catch the exception and call printStackTrace(), at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Firstly*, there is no need to invoke `.newInstance()` on the driver class object. The "classic" way to do is just to call `Class.forName(arg)` in order to force the class to be loaded.

*Secondly*, `Class.forName(arg)` call is redundant and not necessary since JBDC 4, as [`DriverManager` doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) says:

> Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using Class.forName(). Existing programs which currently load JDBC drivers using Class.forName() will continue to work without modification.

*Thirdly*, to benefit from the standard way to configure DB connection in Play! Framework, it could be useful to try it through configuration in `application.conf` file:

```
db.default.driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
db.default.url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/tempdb..."
```

[More details here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDatabase).

*Fourthly*, `% Test` scope in the dependency declaration looks suspicious. If the connection is to be used in the main code of the app, the dependency will be ignored and the class will not be found.

Comment: I set up the configuration in application.conf as you suggested and it found the jar. Please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48912137/setting-up-java-security-attributes-in-play-for-scala)